# Get items in specific folder in Sharepoint online document library with Powershell PNP

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

How to get the column values of the items in a Sharepoint online document library using Powershell PNP?
If all the document would have been in the root folder in the library, this works great.

```
Connect-PnPOnline –Url https://<company>.sharepoint.com/sites/<Site> –Credentials (Get-Credential)
$Item = Get-PnPListItem -List "SampleList" -Fields "Id","TestColumn"
$Item.FieldValues.TestColumn
```

However, I need to query the items in a subfolder that exists in "SampleList". And that seems to be harder.

Accodring to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps) I can use -FolderServerRelativeUrl,

```
Get-PnPListItem -FolderServerRelativeUrl "/sites/<Site>/Lists/SampleList/Folder1"
```

But it cannot find the parameter -FolderServerRelativeUrl....

> Get-PnPFolderItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'FolderServerRelativeUrl'

Any ideas of other cmdlets I can use?

Answer (score 1):

I soon realized that  Get-PnPListItem returns all items, including folders and subfolders :) So I ended up using a Where-Object to filter the items instead.

```
$Item = Get-PnPListItem -List "SampleList" -Fields "Id","TestColumn" | Where-Object {$_.FieldValues.FileRef -like "*Folder1*"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to call the mentioned cmdlet:

> Get-PnPListItem -List Samples -FolderServerRelativeUrl "/sites/contosomarketing/Lists/Samples/Demo"

I tested it on my SP online environment:

- My site url: https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/sbdev
- The library is the default library (Shared Documents)
- Subfolder name:
  [image]

Test:

[image]

So I suggest you have a check the value of 'FolderServerRelativeUrl' then have a try again.

BR